# Fullcalendar recurring event is shifted on next day

Tags: javascript, datetime, fullcalendar, rrule

The issue is, I created an recurring event:

- start date: 10/01/2022
- end date: 10/08/2022
- start time: 12:00am
- end time: 11:59pm
- recurring days: Monday, Tuesday
- frequency: weekly

I am using rrule to get the date occurrences. My rule:

```
let rule = new RRule({
      freq: 2,
      interval: 1,
      byweekday: [0, 1],
      dtstart: "2022-10-01T00:00:00Z",
      until: "2022-10-08T11:59:59Z"
    });
return rule.all();
```

But the event gets pushed forward one day. Event is repeated on Tuesday and Wednesday instead of Monday and Tuesday.

Also, when I create recurring event from like 9:00am to 10:00am, everything is fine.

I know it's related to time zone. Can anyone please suggest me how can I properly set time zone for rrule? Providing 'tzid' doesn't help.

Comment: What is your local timezone where you're viewing the calendar? You've specified the dates there in UTC in your rrule.

Comment: I figured out the issue. It wasn't because of time zone. Thanks for the response though.

Comment: Can you explain what your issue was? I have been running into the same thing.

Comment: In my case, if the event was a full day event (12:00 am to 11:59 pm), it was getting pushed forward one day because I was sending the time along with date in 'dtstart' parameter. I just put a ternary check for full day events and formatted the 'dtstart' accordingly.